# How to initialize Angular UI-Router states properly in unit tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

We have a hybrid AngularJS/Angular 11 app which uses UI-Router for its routing (with the help of [angular-hybrid](https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid)). I'm working on an Angular (11) component that needs to inspect the current router state and all of its ancestors. In particular, it needs to read the param values of those states.

Here's a simplified example of what the component does:

```js
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private uiRouterGlobals: UIRouterGlobals) {}

  parseStates(): void {
    let state = this.uiRouterGlobals.$current;
    while (!!state) {
      if (!state.abstract && !!state.params?.someParam) {
        const paramValue = state.params.someParam.value();
        // Handle the value
      }
      state = state.parent;
    }
  }
```

This works just fine when running the actual app, but the unit tests for the component are causing some trouble. It seems like UI-Router isn't initializing the state registry properly in the tests. The test setup currently looks something like this:

```js
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    imports: [
      UIRouterModule.forRoot({
          {
            name: 'app',
            params: { someParam: 'some value' },
          },
          {
            name: 'app.state1',
            params: { someOtherParam: 'some other value' },
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

During the tests, after transitioning to the state `app.state1` and executing the `parseStates()` function, the following error appears:

`TypeError: someParam.value is not a function`

After debugging the test runs a bit, I noticed that the values in the `params` objects defined in the test states were still strings. When running the actual app, those values are converted into `Param` objects, which have the `value()` function that `MyComponent` uses. AFAIK this conversion happens during application bootstrapping. Maybe this process is different during unit tests? **Is there a way to initialize the UI-Router `StateObjects` in the registry properly during unit tests?**